# hibernate.cfg.xml is not parsed

Tags: hibernate, maven, tomcat

i'm working with hibernate 4 and Maven :

[image]

So the problem is when i start the sever ,i can't see it parsing the hibernate.cfg.xml 
And the table are not created in the dataBase ;

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/mvnodb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="tn.onp.mvno.model.Person" ></mapping>
    <mapping class="tn.onp.mvno.model.User" ></mapping>
    <mapping class="tn.onp.mvno.model.Call" ></mapping>
    <mapping class="tn.onp.mvno.model.User" ></mapping>
 </session-factory>
```

Comment: You have two properties `hibernate.connection.password` there. Is there any exception in the server logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on our setup, Hibernate is typically started by building a SessionFactory. Unless you're using some kind of Spring / JPA integration, this does not automatically happen when you start tomcat.

You can use the following listener to initialize and close Hibernate on deployment and undeployment.

```
public class HibernateListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(); // Just call the static initializer of that class    
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close(); // Free all resources
    }
}
```

You'll need to have this class in your classpath, along with the hibernate jars (+ its dependencies_ and your database driver.

You'll also need to configure the listener in your web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.mypackage.HibernateListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

If there are issues with your hibernate.cfg.xml file, you should see them at startup.